# difference between let inside and outside a lambda expression

Tags: module, scheme, read-eval-print-loop, lexical-scope, guile

Consider a module with the following procedures:

```
(define-module (test test)
  #:export     (proc1 proc2 proc3))

(define proc1
  (let ((module (current-module)))
    (lambda ()
      (format #t "~s\n" module))))

(define proc2
  (lambda ()
    (let ((module (current-module)))
      (format #t "~s\n" module))))

(define (proc3)
  (let ((module (current-module)))
    (format #t "~s\n" module)))
```

I was under the impression that all these were equivalent, but they are not.

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (test test))
scheme@(guile-user)> (proc1)
#<directory (test test) 562a062152d0>
$1 = #t
scheme@(guile-user)> (proc2)
#<directory (guile-user) 562a05b8bbd0>
$2 = #t
scheme@(guile-user)> (proc3)
#<directory (guile-user) 562a05b8bbd0>
$3 = #t
```

Only in `proc1` the `module` symbol inside the lambda expression is bound to the module were the procedure is defined.

Can somebody explain this? Does it mean I always have to use the first form, if I want to create a closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proc1` evaluates `(current-module)` only once, when the procedure is defined, so `module` inside the lambda is bound to that value at definition-time.

`proc2` does not evaluate `(current-module)` until the procedure is called.
It also evaluates it every time.
It is equivalent to `proc3`.

Answer (score 2):

Only proc1 prints the test module.

proc2 and proc3 are equivalent, they print the REPL module.

As well as executing proc1,2,3 try (current-module) in the REPL. It will make things clearer.

For proc1 (current-module) is executed at the time the procedure is defined, for proc2 and proc2 (current-module) is executed at the time the procedure is called.